# LaTex: table rows too lage

Tags: formatting, tables

I just tried to build a table in LaTex and recognized a strange behavior:
 [image: table row is too large]

The last row appeared and is empty, but I don't see how ti remove it.
My LaTex code for this table is:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Sample data of all libraries (two-hour interval)} \\
\hline
Library&Infocenter&A5&A3&Learning Center&Ehrenhof&BWL \\
\hline
Value&152.15 & AF &AFG &AFG&AFG&AFG\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table to test captions and labels}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
```

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this, or where I made the mistake. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) assumes that you will use an `X`-column in order to stretch the table to the specified width. You haven't supplied an `X`-column, which is the cause for the `\textwidth`-span rules exceeding your table width. Either use at least one `X`-column, or avoid `tabularx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}% Also loads array package
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering

  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X| *{6}{|c} | }
    \hline
    \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Sample data of all libraries (two-hour interval)} \\
    \hline
    Library & Infocenter & A5 &  A3 & Learning Center & Ehrenhof & BWL \\
    \hline
    Value   &   152.15   & AF & AFG &      AFG        &    AFG   & AFG \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Table to test captions and labels}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}l *{6}{c} }
    \toprule
    Library & Infocenter & A5 &  A3 & Learning Center & Ehrenhof & BWL \\
    \midrule
    Value   &   152.15   & AF & AFG &      AFG        &    AFG   & AFG \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Sample data of all libraries (two-hour interval)}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The second option provided above uses [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to present the information.

Comment: Thank you! The first solution was the way I was searching for!